# How can we update a screen in Flutter without setState()?

Tags: flutter, dynamic, size, refresh, screen

I will explain, and I'm sorry but I won't be able to paste all my code because it is too long.

So, got a card, in which there is an image. Here is the code of my itemCard :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

import '../models/item.dart';

class CardItem extends StatefulWidget {
  Item item;
  Size sizeItem = Size(0, 28);
  void setSizeItem(Size size) {
    sizeItem = size;
  }

  CardItem(this.item);

  @override
  State<CardItem> createState() => _CardItemState();
}

void updateTransparence(double distance) {}

class _CardItemState extends State<CardItem> {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    setState(() {});

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Card(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: Container(
                height: height -
                    (kToolbarHeight +
                        kBottomNavigationBarHeight +
                        kTextTabBarHeight +
                        kTextTabBarHeight +
                        widget.sizeItem.height),
                width: width - 20,
                child: Image.network(
                  widget.item.pathImage,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 20,
            left: 20,
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.remove_red_eye,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 24,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                CupertinoIcons.info_circle,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 24,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I display the card in an ItemScreen. On this ItemScreen, I got a text at the bottom that will change dynamically in function of the card. So, the text can be bigger and go to 2/3 lines, so I have to dynamically modify the size of the card (the image) in function of the text, because I want to see the full text.

I succeeded the modification of the size, calling setState when didChangeDepencies is called to modify the size of the image in function of the size of the text, BUT even if it changes the image's size, it doesn't "place" the image at the top. I mean, if the text is bigger, the image have to be smaller, and there will have a space between the AppBar and the image, that shouldn't exist. So, the text won't be full displayed, while if it was replaced, we could see the full text.

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTL0p.png) that can help you understand.
On the image, the blue line at the top represents the AppBar, and the white one at the bottom the bottom Bar. After the appBar, there is a space, then the card, then the text that is not fully showed. On this image, it is resized to take into account the size text (2 lines), but the image is not "scrolled" / "replaced", so the resize is quite useless...

I see a similar behavior when I was testing sizes with that. I had to reload the screen to make the card replaced, setState is not enough.

Is there any way to refresh the screen like this ?

Comment: Your question(s) is a bit fuzzy. Maybe you first structure your question. Then you may see, what part of your code is related to your answer and you will be able to extract that part of the code. Short answer, for your problem you need to either use setState or use a state management such as BLoC.

Comment: Is that better? I think it is the part related to my question.